# Making sidebar and content extend to sticky footer

Tags: html, css

I have a page with the following basic layout:

```
<body>
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="wrapper ">
      <div id="sidebar-container"><div id="sidebar"></div></div> 
      <div id="content"></div>
   </div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

The css is like this:

```
#wrapper {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

}

#sidebar-container {
    float:left;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 500px;
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
    background-color: green;
}

#sidebar {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}

#content {
    float: left;
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;

}

#footer {
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100px;
    background: url("footer.jpg") repeat-x scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

At present, the contents of #sidebar-container and #content determine the height of #wrapper. I'd like to get the divs within #wrapper to extent to the footer, which is positioned at the bottom of the browser window. Any suggestions on how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you may need to use `position: fixed` for the sidebar and content. A `height: 100%` doesn't work on elements without a position of `fixed` or `absolute`.

You'll have to update some of your other styles, like removing floats, etc., but I believe what you're trying to do requires fixed or absolute positioning. Read more about the difference here: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Additionally, I would recommend investigating semantic HTML tags like `footer` and `header`. This doesn't affect the layout here, but it would be good to get in the habit.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/HTML5_element_list

Comment: Indeed, setting position to fixed does cause the divs to stretch in the desired fashion. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you support [IE9 and up](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc), you can use [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

```
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100% - {yourFooterHeight}px);
}
#wrapper > * {
  height: 100%;
}
```

**Example**

```css
body, html {
  position: relative;
  width:  100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin:  0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top:  0;
  left: 0;
  width:  100%;
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
}

#wrapper > * {
  height: 100%;
}

#content { background-color: #ebd24b; }

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left:   0;
    width:  100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but doesn't seem to produce any effect when implemented.

Comment: Can you create a JsFiddle with your site structure ? I'll see why it's not working.

Comment: Thanks, Simon! I'll see if I can reproduce the idea in my page's code.

Comment: Seems the 'position' property may have been the key element that was missing. Setting it to fixed or absolute remedies the issue. Thanks again, Simon.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a challenge as you content and sidebar have no relationship i.e. both on same level. You would need to have one of them be the parent of the other or you would need to write some JS. You can use pseudo elements in pure CSS, but in essence you would still need to have one of them "lead" as some element needs to be the box size relationship master.

Example, in Angular I use the following directive. You can then use min-height on the right column to keep a min height, after that it will automatically adjust the left (sidebar) to match the content area:

```
mmeMain.directive('mirror', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
            scope.$watch(function () {
                angular.element(document.getElementById(attr.mirrorReflect)).height(elem.height()-85);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="leftColumn" class=sidebar col-xs-6 ">
 // html code 
</div>

<div id="rightColumn" class="content  form-column col-xs-6"  mirror mirror-reflect="leftColumn" >
 // html code
</div>
```